# SSL-encrypted proxy server for war files in CentOS 7

Tags: proxy, ssl, apache-httpd, tomcat, https

**How can I configure a `CentOS 7` web server to serve only `SSL`-encrypted content from `war` files, with `tomcat` running behind a proxy server?**

I imagine this involves using `firewalld`, `https`, and `tomcat`.  And that `https` is a wrapper for `httpd`.  Currently, `war` files run perfectly on `tomcat` when I expose `tomcat` on port 8080.  But I want to block all outside access to port 8080.  This question is about how to wrap `tomcat` up behind an `SSL`-encrypted `proxy server`.

Here is what I have so far.

The public `zone` in `firewalld` is:

```
[root@xxx-xx-xxx-xx conf]# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (default, active)
  interfaces: enp3s0
  sources: 
  services: https ssh
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

`/usr/lib/firewalld/services/https.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
  <short>Secure WWW (HTTPS)</short>
  <description>HTTPS is a modified HTTP used to serve Web pages when security is important. Examples are sites that require logins like stores or web mail. This option is not required for viewing pages locally or developing Web pages. You need the httpd package installed for this option to be useful.</description>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="443"/>
</service>
```

My `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` can be ready by clicking on [this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/rt8bdF9ebaeYnrjodEng?b=VWMlDrXP4dYnk6wOnrxI).  Note that I deleted a lot of stuff related to file/directory permissions because I just want `httpd` to serve as a proxy for `tomcat`.  I also added a `virtualhost` tag.  Do I need to add anything back into `httpd.conf`?  Also, will `httpd` be called automatically because I added `https` to the `firewalld` public `zone`?

My `/opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml` can be read at [this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/rca1s1ZH7w20MzjnUOWg?b=ppQbrrlE8AWewLtje9gi).

**EDIT:**

Attempting to restart httpd failed.  Here are the results:

```
[username@server.ip.address ~]# systemctl restart httpd.service
Job for httpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

[username@server.ip.address ~]# systemctl status httpd.service -l
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2014-12-11 15:38:00 EST; 59s ago
  Process: 31036 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 31034 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 31034 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Total requests: 0; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"

Dec 11 15:38:00 server.ip.address.static.servdns.com httpd[31034]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 58 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Dec 11 15:38:00 server.ip.address.static.servdns.com httpd[31034]: Invalid command '...///', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Dec 11 15:38:00 server.ip.address.static.servdns.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 11 15:38:00 server.ip.address.static.servdns.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 11 15:38:00 server.ip.address.static.servdns.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
```

**EDIT #2:**

I changed the `virtualhost` tag, added a simple `index.html` file at `/www/example1/index.html`, and then added a document tag to `httpd.conf` as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   DocumentRoot /www/example1/
   SSLEngine on
   SSLProxyEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/some.crt
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/bundle.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/some.key
   # ProxyPass / http://local_host:8080/
   # ProxyPassReverse / http://local_host:8080/
</VirtualHost>  

<Directory "/www/example1/">
     Options None
     AllowOverride None
     allow from all
</Directory>
```

But now typing `https://server.ip.address` into the browser results in `Unable to connect.  Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at server.ip.address`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the sound of it, you're after a `reverse proxy`.  A quick Google will show a good selection of possible solutions.

A simple option is to use the `apache` web server, which you already have installed, as your proxy.

To do this, you need to alter your `httpd.conf` and add:

```
<VirtualHost your.domain.name:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/your_public.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/bundle.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/your_private.key
    ProxyPass / http://ip.addr:8080/myappname
    ProxyPassReverse / http://ip.addr:8080/myappname
</VirtualHost>
```

**Note**: Remove the underscore from `local_host` above - SE won't allow me to post it as it as one word!

There may need to be minor tweaks, depending on your other configurations, but the above should get you started.

Comment: The way I got this to work was to remove the `VirtualHost` directive from `httpd.conf` and to instead add the `SSLProxyEngine`, `ProxyPass`, and `ProxyPassReverse` arguments to the `ssl.conf` file.  Also, some of the errors I encountered were due to the `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLKeyFile` being defined in both `ssl.conf` and `httpd.conf`.  The errors persisted when I removed them from `ssl.conf` only, but I was able to get the `https` requests for the domain to work when I removed them from `httpd.conf` only. +1 and thank you for all your time.

Comment: @CodeMed - Glad you got there in the end.  If I were you, I'd still move the configuration to a separate file. If you don't the next update of `httpd` will be a pain.

Comment: For the purposes of documentation, changing the `http:` in `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` to `ajp:` and also un-commenting the `ajp connector` in `server.xml` were required to get this working.  In addition, it is a good precaution to put `/` after `myappname` in order to reconcile relative urls.